# how to embed a image into robot framework log file from Custom Library written in python?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

how to embed a image into robot framework log file from Custom Library written in python?

I wanted to display a image into Robot report , how to do it programmatically not from keyword file

I tried this way but format in the second line seems to be wrong , how to give image as input here

```
from robot.api import logger
logger.info(<a img src="image.png"></a>,html=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to embed an image, use the `<img>` tag:

```
from robot.api import logger
logger.info("<img src='image.png'/>", html=True)
```

Comment: awesome , thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley it woks and straightforward